# Do pengulls reappear to breed on the same location in the next winters?

Tags: dont-starve

When winter begins, pengulls start jumping out of the ocean and assume a random spot in the world as their breeding ground. That spot has thin layer of ice and is marked on the map. But when the next winter starts, pengulls don't seem to repopulate all their previously inhabited spots. It might have been because the last time they were there they were exploded by some gunpowder.

Do these pengull spots rotate each winter, or do they only not repopulate locations that have proven to be bad in the past?

Comment: Good question! Not sure actually. I'd expect each pengull location to be random, every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon information from the [Don't Starve Wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Pengull) and my own in-game experience:

The breeding grounds appear to be random each time.  The map will continue to show pengull sites even when they're not actively being used.  And, every time I've seen a pengull spawn, they've gone to a new frozen spot adding another pengull picture to the map.

I've never blown them up with gunpowder, nor have I attacked them in any manner.  So, that rules it out as the cause of relocation.